# Passing data to PHP from Jquery using ajax without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I asked a similar question already, but I wasn't able to get enough information. I tried reducing the code to just the what I needed for this to work.

I am trying to pass the php code a title variable and I want the php code to give me a success message when it finishes. I wanted to do this without refreshing the page.

When I run this code without the ajax bit in there, it will let me click the button and it will preform the checks without refreshing. But once I put the ajax code in, it will not preform the checks and it WILL refresh. It also doesn't run any checks in the php code.

Am I using the ajax code wrong? How can I get this to send the data to the php file without refreshing and send me back a success message?

EDIT: I added in the brackets around the data being sent to the php file. Now the "fill out the form" check works. But when the form is filled out the success check isn't returning from the php file.

EDIT2: I inserted .val() into the initiation statement and removed the .val() from the if statement. I removed the onclick attribute from the button. And updated the data in JS to "data: {title1:title},". So far status remains the same.

EDIT3: I added "dataType: JSON," as well as some error/success codes. Thank you Ron for your help with that. Now when I submit I get an xhr status of 500 with a blank response text. I've been looking around for a solution, but nothing so far.

EDIT4: I changed the title1's to title's so that there was no longer a confusion on that. Now it's working correctly! Thank you Ron for your help.

```js
<?php
//getting values from JS
$title = $_POST['title'];

if(!$title == "")
{
  $res="Data received successfully:";
  echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
  $error="Not received,some problem occurred.";
  echo json_encode($error);
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <title>Insert</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   
    //debug
    var x =  document.getElementById("msg");
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var director = $('#director').val();
    var genre = $('#genre').val();
    var runtime = $('#runtime').val();
       
       
       if( title=="" || year=="" || director=="" || genre=="" || runtime=="" ) {
        x.style.color = "red";
        x.innerHTML = "Please fill out all of the blanks.";
       } else {
        //is the value being sent correct?
        x.style.color = "lightGreen";
        x.innerHTML = "Title is: "+title+ 
          "<br>Year is: "+year+
          "<br>Director is: "+director+
          "<br>Genre is: "+genre+
          "<br>Runtime is: "+runtime;
        
        $.ajax({  
     type: "POST",
     url: "insert_DVD.php",
     data: {
      title: title,
      year: year,
      director: director,
      genre: genre,
      runtime: runtime,
      },
     dataType: "JSON",
     error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, data) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
      alert(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(data);
     },
     success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
         return false;
        }
    });
  });
 </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webpage.css">
  </head>
  <body class="subStyle">
   
 <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Database</a>
    <a class="active" href="#">Insert</a>
 </div>
 
 <form id="form" method="post">
  If there is more than one director, separate with comma.
  <table border=0>
  <tr>
  <th>Movie Title</th>
  <th>Year Made</th>
  <th>Director</th>
  <th>Genre</th>
  <th>Runtime(Minutes)</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td><input type=text name="title"    id="title"    maxlength=100 size=30></td>
  <td><input type=text name="year"     id="year"     maxlength=4   size=10></td>
  <td><input type=text name="director" id="director" maxlength=100 size=30></td>
  <td><input type=text name="genre"    id="genre"    maxlength=20  size=20></td>
  <td><input type=text name="runtime"  id="runtime"  maxlength=4   size=20></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr><td>
  <button type="submit" id="update" value="send">Update Database</button></td></tr>
  </table>
 </form>
 
 <p id="msg">Click the update button.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the console say? `data: title:title1` this should be throwing a syntax error

Comment: I fixed this by adding the {}, so now it reads data:{title:title1},

It is now doing the "fill out form" check in the js. But it still isn't sending the check from the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at my dev computer so I can't really test the php side of things but you do have two javascript errors, one of which might be causing the issue.

*Not causing your issue but causing an error in the console.*

1) Remove the passData() function from the onclick.  It's not needed since you're watching for the form submission already with the .submit.

*Might be causing your issue*

2) When you're defining "title1" you're not getting its value which will cause an HTMLFormElement.toString error when submitting the form currently.  Instead go ahead and get the value when defining title 1 via:

`$('#title').val();`

and then remove title1.val() out of the if statement where you check if its been populated and instead just put title1 == ""

Right now you're sending an HTML element via that ajax call which will cause jquery to fail.  Put another way you currently are sending:

```
data: {title: (HTML ELEMENT)}
```

Let me know if that fixes it or not.  If it doesn't I'll pull this up when I get to where I can run PHP.

***EDIT***: Also, as pointed out in one of the comments you'll need to change your PHP to be $_POST['title'] in order to match what you're sending.  You can verify what is happening on the php side of things by echoing out some errors.  It's been a really long time since I've done any php but I would usually do something like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

At the top of my scripts while working on them in order to debug them.  This will pass the error from php back to the Ajax response if there is one.  That was back in PHP 5 days though.

***EDIT2***: This is how I got it to work

test.php

```
<?php
  //getting values from JS
  $title = $_POST['title'];

  if(!$title == "") {
    $res="Data received su ccessfully:";
    echo json_encode($res);
  } else {
    $error="Not received,some problem occurred.";
    echo json_encode($error);
  }
?>
```

index.html just the ajax part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //debug
    var x = document.getElementById("msg");
    var title1 = $('#title').val();



    if (title1 == "") {
        x.style.color = "red";
        x.innerHTML = "Please fill out all of the blanks.";
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {
                title: title1
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;

    }
});
});
```

Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to explain what was changed but I will get to that tomorrow!  (Hopefully :)

Also, I did not put the success message in the html, I forgot, and instead am console.logging the response which you can see in the browser console.  Sorry I wish I had more time tonight to respond.

Comment: I removed the onclick attribute and added the .val() to the title variable. I also removed the .val() from the if statement. From what I can tell the status hasn't changed. I can still see the checks in the JS but not the PHP.

Comment: I updated the data to "data:{title1:title},". I wasn't sure if it mattered that the variable being pulled in was the same name as the variable used on the php side. Hence the extra 1. If it doesn't matter though, I can just call all of it title.

Comment: I added the dataType: JSON, as well as your error and success codes. 
With it I was able to get error codes at least. It's throwing an error 500: Internal Server Error. Not really sure what this means just yet, but I feel like I'm a lot closer to getting this working than before. Thank you!

Comment: From my phone.  I'm glad you're not just taking what I have as you'll learn a lot more this way... which I don't mean to sound patronizing or anything.  

A 500 error is good because it means the error is on the php side which we can find if you put this at the top of the PHP:

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

That will most certainly error out every time there is an issue or warning at the php level but you'll be able to see what the problem is.  Ultimately, put that in now and remove later once you fix all of the issues.

Comment: That's great that it's in the php file. 
I put the error reporting in, but I didn't get any information out. (I should mention that I am testing this on the website, not a local test. I am trying to do database work and don't have a set up for a local database.) I looked up error reporting stuff, and I tried to echo out the int_set but still didn't get anything. I still get the 500 error, but nothing after. Am I supposed to set up a print out for it?

Comment: Did you add an error handler in your ajax function?  Something like...

error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },

If so what is it returning?

Comment: The error prompts are; status is 500, the thrownError is internal server error, and the responseText is blank.

Comment: Hey, is your code above up to date?  If so looks like at some point we changed the variable name again data: {title1:title},  Second title should be title1.  Unless you forgot to update it :)

Comment: I just changed everything to "title" I don't think there is an error with using the same name. so now it should all be right.

Comment: When I changed everything it says that it was successful! So I know that the data is being sent to the test php file! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

May be it should be an object

```
data: {title1:title1}
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding the {}, so now it reads data:{title:title1}, It is now doing the "fill out form" check in the js. But it still isn't sending the check from the php

Comment: This answer has already been addressed in my comment, and doesn't solve his issue

Comment: at the backend part, you try to cathc the parameter by this $_POST['title1'];
so at the jquery data, should be {title1: ... }

Comment: I updated the data section to read "data: {title1:title}," it hasn't changed the status though. But this could keep a future error from occurring. Thank you.